# Register form minimum characters for password and username

Tags: php

How can i force password and username to have a minimum lenght in PDO?
I could do it my self in a simple input field using PHP, but with this PDO register system I have no clue how to do it, or where to do it. Im not good with PHP and even worse with PDO.

Register form:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. ;
            die('
                        <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Please enter a username
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                '); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Please enter a password
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                '); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Invalid E-mail address.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                '); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this.
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Please try agian.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Username is already taken.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                '); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Please try again.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die('
                <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        This E-mail is already in use by someone ells.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                '); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read.
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die('
                      <div class="notice fail">
                    <div class="notice-p">
                        Something went wrong!<br />
                        Please try again.
                    </div>
                </div><br />
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        ob_clean();
        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: /signin/"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die(); 

    } 


//session to store input after die() function
?>
```

Comment: You dont do it in PDO, you do it in the HTML or javascript and then again in PHP code before you get as far as the database and PDO

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You could merge at least 2 of your queries with the use of `WHERE username = :username OR email = :email`

Comment: ***Crazy little thing called*** `strlen()`, you should look it up sometime, you might ***love*** it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought password salt in sha2 and custom salt was secure? why should i not use it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- well thats what i whould have used in php, but is it the same in PDO?

Comment: The `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take a lots of the heavy lifting out of hashing, and guarantee to do it right (where we non experts often make little mistakes with BIG BAD consequences)

Comment: PDO is not something different from PHP. It is part of PHP.

Comment: as @RiggsFolly already said; you can't. why is it so important that you want to do this in PDO? now you've been given an answer below with what I said to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its not that it is so important, its that i want to learn why i should do it that way. if i came just to get the answer and not learn i might aswell just hire someone to make it all for me

Comment: Remember good old WEP used on routers. All the technology was perfectly good. It was just implemented badly by non security experts and not correctly tested. Thats what I mean by us normal folk making little mistakes with encryption and hashing with unfortunately HUGE consequences

Comment: Eh @Fred-ii- I thought that ___Crazy little thing___ was called **LOVE()**

Comment: @RiggsFolly You got the general gist ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, right after your check if the form was submiited, lets see how long those are...

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
// check length of $_POST['username']

    if (strlen($_POST['username']) <5){
          die('
                    <div class="notice fail">
                <div class="notice-p">
                Usernames need to be 5 characters or longer
                </div>
            </div><br />
            '); 
    }

  // check length of $_POST['password']

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) <5){
          die('
                    <div class="notice fail">
                <div class="notice-p">
                Passwords need to be 5 characters or longer
                </div>
            </div><br />
            '); 
    }
```