# Prevent die() from removing everything below

Tags: php

In my registration code I have several `die()` "functions", like if the username is empty, or in use, email, password, etc. The point is, every time something goes wrong I use `die()` but this will cause the page to not render everything below the `die()` "function".

What whould be the best way to prevent this?
I was thinking of doing something like

```
<?php $page = ?>
<body>
  <p>Page information here</p>
</body>
<?php ; ?>
```

but this whould ofc not work as I had planed.
Second idea was to store every `die()` in a variable so I could then late use

```
<div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

and maybe store the whole registration code at the bottom of the footer and make it only load if the url was `/register/`.
But what is the best way to deal with something like this?

Register.php:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
      // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
      if(!empty($_POST)) {

        // check length of $_POST['username']
        if (strlen($_POST['username']) <3){
          die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    The username is too short (requier atleast 3 characters).
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
          '); 
        }

        // check length of $_POST['password']
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) <5){
          die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    Your password is too short (requier atleast 5 characters)!
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
          '); 
        }
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. ;
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    Please enter a username.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                '); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    Password cant be empty.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                '); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    Please enter a valid E-mail address.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                '); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this.
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    We where not able to process your information.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    Username is already taken
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                '); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    We where not able to process your information. Please try again.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    E-mail address is already taken.
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                '); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read.
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die('
              <div class="container">
                <div class="flag note note--error">
                  <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flag__body note__text">
                    Something went wrong!<br />
                    We where not able to process your information. Please try again
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="note__close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
                ' . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        ob_clean();
        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        echo'
          <div class="container">
            <div class="flag note note--info">
              <div class="flag__image note__icon">
                <i class="fa fa-info"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="flag__body note__text">
                <p>Successfull!<br />
                We have sent you an E-mail With a verification link. Please use the link to verify your account,
                and complete your registration.</p>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="note__close">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ';

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die(); 

    } 


//session to store input after die() function
?>
```

Comment: what `die()` does and is *supposed to to*: stop execution of the script. its whole purpose is to "not render anything below it" because there was an unrecoverable error.

Comment: It's hard to know where to start with this ... `// Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors` < you've even pointed out your #1 flaw right there ... then there's a load of stuff about creating custom salt - which is also bad, `password_hash()` exists for a reason ... in short, throw it out and start again - sorry.

Comment: If you dont want to `die` you could always consider `echo`

Comment: @CD001 I already told OP about `password_hash()` [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753736/register-form-minimum-characters-for-password-and-username) So we may both be wasting our breath here

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh well, at least I don't feel bad now for thinking that this code is an abomination that should be cleansed with fire - but was trying to think of a *nice (ish)* way to put it... ;)

Comment: @CD001 Fire.... sounds good

Comment: @CD001 Or maybe we could say ... The code needs a bit of refactoring! With a machete

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... to begin the refactoring process we shall first hit **Ctrl + A** (assuming a Windows system) ... next, please hit the **Del** key...

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `echo` instead. `die` is equivalent to `exit`, which would obviously exit your script after executing.

Comment: i could but that whould cause a problem where even if the code stumble upon a problem that ive set to display a error message, it whould just continue and in the end register a user without username or password

Comment: @martinj So maybe you just need to .... I think the polite term is **refactor** the code from the ground up

Comment: @RiggsFolly Since you pointed out my question from yesterday i might aswell quote myself "Im not good with PHP and even worse with PDO". with other words, not my code, just trying to learn how it all works.

Comment: @martinj learning how it all works is good ... but take baby steps man, don't start with bizarre output buffering, abuse of `die()` and database driven user systems. Start with something simpler - ideally something you *want* to make. One of my earliest PHP projects was simply for managing the roster of characters in my Ultima Online guild 12 bazillion years ago - it was basic as all hell and if I was to find the code for it now it would probably set my teeth on edge - but it was something **I wanted** to make; and that makes all the difference.

Comment: @martinj If you are working from a tutorial, A) Find a better one B) Find a simpler one, baby steps. We all have to start out as Noobs, nothing wrong with that, but take steps you can easily deal with

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have been doing php for awhile thats why i want a login system now. finding one that is secure and works the way i want it to is hard, wich is why i was told to create my own. to create my own i need knowledge, and to get knowledge i ask questions.
thats why ive been asking questions about this registration form. I want to know what makes it secure, what do what and how. in this question i wanted to know if there was a easier way to kill the php script without killing the whole thing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796825/password-verify-dont-work-changing-custom-password-hash-to-password-hash